# Tomcat ran into an infinite loop

Tags: java, tomcat, struts2

I am developing an application using Apache Struts2, and Hibernate. I am using Apache Tomcat application server. Suddenly I notice that my server is continuously printing these lines

```
WARNING: No configuration found for the specified action: 'addProject' in namespace: ''. Form action defaulting to 'action' attribute's literal value.
Apr 12, 2016 2:30:23 PM org.apache.struts2.components.ServletUrlRenderer warn
WARNING: No configuration found for the specified action: 'addProject' in namespace: ''. Form action defaulting to 'action' attribute's literal value.
Apr 12, 2016 2:30:23 PM org.apache.struts2.components.ServletUrlRenderer warn
WARNING: No configuration found for the specified action: 'studentMailbox' in namespace: ''. Form action defaulting to 'action' attribute's literal value.
Apr 12, 2016 2:30:23 PM org.apache.struts2.components.ServletUrlRenderer warn
WARNING: No configuration found for the specified action: 'studentMailbox' in namespace: ''. Form action defaulting to 'action' attribute's literal value.
Apr 12, 2016 2:30:23 PM org.apache.struts2.components.ServletUrlRenderer warn
WARNING: No configuration found for the specified action: 'addProject' in namespace: ''. Form action defaulting to 'action' attribute's literal value.
Apr 12, 2016 2:30:24 PM org.apache.struts2.components.ServletUrlRenderer warn
```

During this interval my web page is running with some sign of hanging application.But after 2 minutes i notice that tomcat stops and browser displays

```
AW,Snap
Something went wrong while displaying this page
```

Please suggest me a solution .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any error page defection in `web.xml`

Comment: Please also check if your browser keeps sending request ( for example with fire bug)

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi no i don't have any error page defection in my web.xml .I don't know how to check that the browser is still sending the request or not

Comment: Install firefox install firebug add on and check the network tab on firebug

Answer (score 0):

There can be any reason behind the generation of this exception. Among them let's first concentrate on following 2 points that can be responsible for this exception.

First check that struts.xml file is lying at proper place in project. Because if Struts2 is not able to load struts.xml file, this exception can be occure.

And second, do not use namespace attribute in struts.xml file, if you have used.

Please refer the following link for the better understanding of namespace :
http://struts.apache.org/docs/namespace-configuration.html